# A-frame: How to attach an object to a point on a model (and/or it's bones)

Tags: aframe

I want to attach an object* to a particular bone, so it moves along with that bone (think putting a hat on a character's head, say). In three.js, I could do something like:

```
mesh.skeleton.bones[someindex].add(mesh2)
```

What's the best way to do this in a-frame?

An alternative might be to parent an object to a specific vertex on the model, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

*: By "object", I think I mean "entity with position and rotation" in A-frame terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, [a-frame](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html#example) has only a small API for working with models build on `Three.js` loaders. (+ Don McCurdys animation mixer).

The only "A-Frame" touch i can think of here is creating, and accessing the base model. Having:

```
<a-entity gltf-model="url(model.gltf)" foo>
```

You can create an a-frame component which will grab the model, and attach the new mesh to the bone:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init:function() {
    let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
    // or this.el.components["gltf-model"].model
    let mesh2; // get create the model using any THREE loader
    mesh.skeleton.bones[someindex].add(mesh2)
  }
})
```

---

I can't think of any major benefit if you create the hat via `<a-element gltf-model="url(hat.gltf)">` and try to position and rotate it using `setAttribute()` on each render loop (in the `tick()` function).