# How to attach an camera to a bone/vertices on a model without affecting its rotation? (A-Frame)

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, aframe, gltf

I wish to attach a first-person camera to the head of an animated GTLF model. I intend to remove the model's head and merged the neck into one vertex as to not obstruct the camera. My question is how do I attach my camera to the vertice or bone of the model?

This is similar to:
[A-frame: How to attach an object to a point on a model (and/or it's bones)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492696/a-frame-how-to-attach-an-object-to-a-point-on-a-model-and-or-its-bones) but I also wish the player to still rotate the camera independently from the parent. How do I only affect the camera's position?

Currently, I have the following code:

**Javascript**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('character-logic', {
    init: function () {
        var character = document.querySelector('#character')
        var camera = document.querySelector('#camera')
        character.skeleton.bones[2].add(camera)
    }
});
```

**HTML Summary**

```
<a-scene character-logic>
   <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="character-gtlf" src="models/character.glb" response-type="arraybuffer"></a-asset-item>
   </a-assets>
   <a-camera id="camera"></a-camera> 
   <a-entity id="character" gltf-model="#character-gtlf" animation-mixer></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

But I keep getting "Cannot read property 'bone'" for some reason.

If it helps, I also have a simple code example on Glitch here which works when the `character.skeleton.bones[2].add(camera)` is commented out: [https://glitch.com/~cam-to-bone](https://glitch.com/%7Ecam-to-bone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to append the camera to a bone by using this approach:

```js
character.addEventListener('model-loaded', function(event){
    const model = event.detail.model;
    const skinnedMesh = model.getObjectByName('nedKelly001');
    skinnedMesh.skeleton.bones[2].add(camera.object3D);
});
```

The idea is to query the skinned mesh by its name `nedKelly001`. You can then safely access the `skeleton` property.

Comment: Thank you, Mugen87 ! Looks like I have more research to do into Three.js... This code almost works perfectly but I cannot get the camera to be the correct direction as the character. It is currently 180 degrees the opposite way and setting `<a-camera id="camera" rotation="0 180 0"><a-camera>` doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

I also have the rotation of the model affecting the camera, but I can work around this by removing keyframes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not that deep into A-Frame so it's probably better to ask a separate question about this.

Comment: All good! Figure out creating an entity around the camera can allow this functionality. Cameras cannot easily be adjusted due to VR controls https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3450